# What is the meaning of "as a touch of elegance"?

Tags: grammar, expressions

A calligrapher is called upon to design and write announcements, place cards, etc, **as a touch of elegance.**

What does "as a touch of elegance" mean? what does it modify？ Does it modify the whole sentence or just the subject "a calligrapher"?

Comment: *A touch of elegance* = *a bit of elegance*.  But "touch" is thought to be more elegant than "bit." / I think this sentence is sort of short for *A calligrapher is called upon to design and write announcements, place cards, etc., as a means of providing a touch of elegance [to the announcements, place cards, etc.].*

Answer (score 1):

The elegance derives from the notion that a personally prepared, beautifully hand-written (calligraphic) and expensive card reflects the elegant and stylish nature of the occasion, rather than using a cheap (machine-printed or scribbled) card that undiscerning people might use or afford.

The touch (hint, or subtle suggestion) of elegance is given by the nature of the design of the cards. And what nature is implied by the sentence? - calligraphic. The phrase does not modify the calligrapher, who is merely the assumedly tasteful agent of the design. Nor does it modify the physical cards themselves.

There is an unexpressed adjectival descriptor in such sentences.

*… cards (written) as a touch of elegance*
*… cards (printed) for convenience and neatness*
*… cards (bought pre-printed) for cheapness*

Or in this case:
*… cards (calligraphically written) as a touch of elegance*

From this viewpoint, the phrase modifies the unspoken adjectival descriptor of the cards.